# hostname from list of iptables

Tags: ip, hostname

Edited:

How can I get it to print the IP address with the hostname?

ie. 
IP_ADDR,hostname
IP_ADDR,hostname
IP_ADDR,hostname

```
Get-Content C:\IPList.txt | ForEach-Object {([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname >> c:\hostname.txt}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may scann your network using a networkscanner like advanced ip scanner. This will give you ip + hostname and you can save it as csv.

Comment: Not allowed to install a program. I edited my original question to include the script I am running, but it does not output the hostname. Nor can I figure out how to put the IP list back in with the hostname